# css. растяжка блока по ширине body если родительский элемент уже, чем body

Tags: html, css

Есть блок, который лежит в блоке `content`, этот `content` ограничен по ширине, но надо, что бы мой блок занял всю ширину в видимой области (т.е. как если бы родителем был body), при этом, что бы кроссбраузерность боле-менее сохранилась. В меню была та же проблема - сделал костыль - позади полоска в цвет меню с абсолютным позиционированием. как сделать со слайдером не знаю, может есть более простой способ о котором нужно знать?
структура примерно такова:

```
-body style="width:100%"(занял всю видимую ширину)

--div id="content" style="width:70%"

---div id="slider" style="width:100%"

текст

---/div

--/div

-/body
```

Ещё раз суть вопроса более кратко: растянуть `#slider` по ширине `body`, при этом не поломав верстку.

Comment: Вам стоит добавить свой код в вопрос.

Comment: всю html разметку? я поэтому и дал ссылку, с браузерным отладчиком проще понять что к чему.

Comment: Здесь люди предпочитают отвечать на качественные вопросы с детальным описанием проблемы без лишних деталей. А не лезть по ссылкам, вникать, что и к чему.

Comment: HTML и CSS не моя тема, я так, просто по-дружески советую :)

Comment: спасибо, я учту

Comment: Примени абсолютное позиционирование для слайдера.

Comment: пробовал, верстка ломается. @lexxl ниже предложил хороший вариант, я им воспользовался

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если я правильно вас понял, то вам необходимо разместить слайдер на всю ширину документа, но весь свой контент вы предпочли разместить в контейнере (.content), который ограничивает ширину. так вот, в таком случае лучше в этот контейнер оборачивать каждый ваш блок, который необходимо ограничить по ширине, а блок со слайдером не оборачивать и дать ему ширину 100%.

примерно вот так:

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <header>...</header>
    <nav>...</nav>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <main>...</main>
</div>

<div class="slider">...</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <footer>...</footer>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
wrapper { width: 1024px;}
```

Answer (score -1):

Стилизация по `id` плохая практика, создайте отдельный класс типа `.container` и им ограничивайте то содержимое которое нужно центровать.